# How to pass different arguments to a function based on which element was clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new to this, so if I'm not too explicit please don't be too harsh to me.

I made an HTML file with two test buttons.

I created a function called `test()` in JavaScript which includes an Ajax POST method to the file `test.php`.

The PHP file writes `1` and `0` to a text file named `test.txt`.

All this for one button.

Everything works fine, but I have this problem:

I want my `test()` function to be called in the second button which has different data like `test2.php` and other 4 variables like `tag_test2`, `phptag_test2` , `On_test2`, `toggle_test2`.

So would need to write a function `test(testphp, tag, phptag, toggle, On)` to call it for those two buttons with different parameters.

I've tried this function.

```js
function test(testphp, tag, phptag, On, toggle) {

    if (toggle_test == 0) {
        toggle = 1;
        On = 1;
        tag = On;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = On;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: testphp,
            data: {
                phptag: tag
            }
        });

        return test;
    }

    if (toggle == 1) {
        toggle = 0;
        On = 0;
    }
    tag = On;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = On;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: testphp,
        data: {
            phptag: tag
        }
    });
}
}
```

And called it in my first button to see if it works, but no success so far.

I replaced `test()` with `test('test.php', tag_test, phptag_test, On_test, toggle_test)`.

This is my code that works for the first button:

*test.html*

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Tests</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <div>
   </div>
   <div class="Header2"> Cornel - Tests</div>
   <div class="space"></div>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
            onclick="test()">Test</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Test2</button>
         <div id="result"></div>
         <script>
var toggle_test = 0;
var On_test = 0;
var tag_test;

function test() {

    if (toggle_test == 0) {
        toggle_test = 1;
        On_test = 1;
        tag_test = On_test;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = On_test;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {
                phptag_test: tag_test
            }
        });

        return test;
    }

    if (toggle_test == 1) {
        toggle_test = 0;
        On_test = 0;
    }
    tag_test = On_test;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = On_test;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {
            phptag_test: tag_test
        }
    });
}
         </script>
         <style>
.btn-success {
    background-color: #2E64FE;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.btn-success:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.btn-success:active:focus {
    background-color: blue;
}

.btn-success:focus {
    background-color: #2E64FE;
}

.btn-success:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.Header2 {
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#0033cc, #58FAF4);
    border: solid;
}

.space {
    padding: 25px;
}

.container {
    padding-left: 80px
}
         </style>
      </div>
   </body>
```

*test.php*

```
<?php
$tag_test = $_POST['phptag_test'];



$file=fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, $tag_test . "\n");
fclose($file);
?>
```

This writes in the `test.txt` file.

Also I have a `jquery-3.4.1.js` file in my folder.

Comment: fyi, in your original post, where there was meant to be a closing bracket on your `.space` and `.container` classes in your HTML code sample, there were actually opening brackets. have fixed that and improved formatting of the other code samples, see revisions here:  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57453721/revisions

Comment: I’m on mobile at the moment, but if you want to call the same function when clicking two different buttons, and have different handling for each instance, you could give each button a unique `id`, and then create a click handler like `$(document).on(“click”, “#button1, #button2”, function() { });` and create conditional handling within the click handler based on the value of the id attribute of the button, eg: `var instance = $(this).attr(“id”);`, eg `if (instance === “button1”) { test(parameters) } else if (instance === “button2”) { test(different_parameters) }`.

Comment: also note that you have assigned ‘fixed’ values at the beginning of your script tags, but then have two if statements based on the value of `toggle_test` .  it should be an `if/else if` statement and the value assignment should be dynamic, otherwise, as it is currently written, only the first condition will ever be true.  also you should put `var`, `let` or `const` before your variable names.  more info about if statements is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: and you can learn more about the different types of variable declarations in articles like this: https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I think resolves your primary issue, ie passing dynamic values to a function.

Basically, the approach is to:

- add a unique `id` attribute to each button
- add an on click handler
- define different function parameters depending on which button was clicked

You will then be able to handle your different scenarios via conditional handling of the values passed through to your server side code.

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/qhycm3zv)

*note:  the jsFiddle uses `mockjax` to emulate a delay when retrieving results from the server, and logs several values to the console so you can better understand what is happening in the code, but you can remove all that code when implementing*

**HTML**

```html
<!-- added unique id's to your buttons -->
<div class="container">
  <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Test1</button>
  <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Test2</button>

  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```js
// added on click handler
$(document).on("click", "#button1, #button2", function() {

  // get reference to the instance of the button  
  var instance = $(this).attr("id");

  // sanity check  
  console.log("the instance is: " + instance);

  // create an object to store function parameters
  var parameters = {};

  // assign different values based on the instance  
  if (instance === "button1") {

    parameters.php_file = "my_file_1.php";
    parameters.tag = "tag 1";
    parameters.phptag = "php tag 1";
    parameters.is_toggled = true;
    parameters.is_on = false;

  } else if (instance === "button2") {

    parameters.php_file = "my_file_2.php";
    parameters.tag = "tag 2";
    parameters.phptag = "php tag 2";
    parameters.is_toggled = false;
    parameters.is_on = true;

  }

  // call the function
  my_function(parameters);

});


const my_function = (parameters) => {

  var php_file = parameters.php_file;

  $.ajax({
    url: `/path/to/your/file/${php_file}`,
    data: parameters, // send the parameters to your server side file
    type: "POST", 
    success: function(response) {

      // handle the response here  
      $("#result").text(response);

    }
  });

}
```

**CSS**

```css
.btn-success {
  background-color: #2E64FE;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn-success:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.btn-success:focus {
  background-color: #2E64FE;
}

.btn-success:active:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}

.Header2 {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0033cc, #58FAF4);
  border: solid;
}

.space {
  padding: 25px;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

#instance {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}

#result {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: deeppink;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! I must recognize I'm really new to this. I'll try to implement this solution just for my curiosity and to gather more knowledge in coding.

Comment: Being at the beginning I just want to keep the things more simple. It would have been more helpful to just call a function like test(var1a, var2a) for the first button and another function like test(var1b, var2b) for the second. I might be in need to write simple functions for each button, rather than multiple if's, that just to be more clear for me. However, thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: i understand, i removed the mockjax and logging info from the answer so that the logic is easier to understand (all of that is still available in the jsFiddle though).

Answer (score 0):

Just my idea. How about you will detect the button which is been clicked and throw a condition that if the button2 is been clicked then do your ajax call and the same thing with button1.

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="button1" onclick="test(this.id)">Test</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="button2" onclick="test(this.id)">Test2</button>
   <script>
     function test(button_id) {
          if(button_id == "button1"){
            // do your ajax here
          }else if(button_id == "button2"){
            // do your ajax here
          }
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: Instead of writing the ajax twice, it would be better to set some variables for the ajax which would be called under the if/else conditions.

Comment: Yeah, that would be also great.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to just pass the Data in the `onClick` events.

**Example**

Pass the urls file name and the data string like so.

```
<button id="test" name="test" onClick="Test('test1', 'test_string_1');">Click Me </button>
<button id="test" name="test" onClick="Test('test2', 'test_string_2');">Click Me </button>
```

And then if your `Test` function use them like this.

```
function Test (filename, data){

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: filename + ".php",
        data: {
            phptag_test: data
        }
    });
}
```

*This is just a psuedo example, you will need to write your own version for your desired functionality.*

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your support. This is what I kind of tried. The problem is it gets stuck somewhere. I don't know why and where. It gives me result=1 in the web browser, but when I click it again, it does nothing and my .txt file in empty.

Comment: What does it say in the console?, if it's not working it would throw an error as to why

Answer (score 0):

After a pause from this miniproject, I came up with a solution.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="test(iluminat1);iluminat1()">Iluminat1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="test(iluminat2);iluminat2()">Iluminat2</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var toggle_test=0;
        var On_test=0;
        var php_iluminat1;
        var php_iluminat2;


        function test(tag_test) {


                if(toggle_test==0)
                {
                toggle_test=1;
                On_test=1;
                return test;
                }


                if(toggle_test==1)
                {
                toggle_test=0;
                On_test=0;
                }

        }

        function iluminat1()
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {php_iluminat1: On_test}
        });
        }


        function iluminat2()
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {php_iluminat2: On_test}
        });
        }

    </script>
```

I didn't need all those parameters and I realized I need to write an individual function for each button to be able to write their `On_test` value.