# Create pop-up with content changing depending on trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have been trying to create a pop-up window on the page with changing content depending on which trigger is clicked on.

Unfortunately, the JS code just keeps adding the created elements to the pop-up div, which works fine on the first click but then it overruns the container.

Is there a better way to create a pop-up window with dynamic content that displays the corresponding content to each trigger?

*I also created a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/lisaschumann/pen/eYOZoMW.*

When I create a single pop-up with the HTML code already in the index.html file and just change the 'display: none;' and 'display: block;' properties with JS it works fine. But if I want to create a pop-up with different content from an array depending on which trigger, it gets really confusing.

// I'm trying to avoid jQuery for this one as the code needs to be implemented into a WordPress page and any additional jQuery code has caused issues with the rest of the template.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div class="trigger" id="profile-one">
  <span>Click here for Profile Dan</span>
</div>
<div class="trigger" id="profile-two">
  <span>Click here for Profile Tom</span>
</div>

<div class="pop-up">
  <div class="close-button"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pop-up {
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 32%;
}

.pop-up p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 40px;
}

.pop-up h4{
  margin: 32px 0 20px 40px;
}

.bio {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 80px 40px 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.bio img {
    width: 25%;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 10px 30px 0 0;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}
.close-button:before, .close-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.close-button:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close-button:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.trigger {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#profile-one {
  top: 15%;
  left: 10%;
}

#profile-two {
  top: 55%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

**JS**

```
const triggerOne = document.querySelector('.trigger#profile-one');
const triggerTwo = document.querySelector('.trigger#profile-two');
const popUp = document.querySelector('.pop-up')
const close = document.querySelector('.close-button');

const profile = [{
       name: 'Dan',
        src: 'https://lisaschumann.github.io/resources/images/mark-basarab-157610-unsplash.jpg',
      alt: 'Dan Profile Pic',
        bio: 'Bio Dan: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        src: 'https://lisaschumann.github.io/resources/images/osteopathy.jpg',
      alt: 'Tom Profile Pic',
        bio: 'Bio Tom: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'
    }
     ];

function profileOne() {
var divMain = document.createElement("div");
var titleProfile = document.createElement("h4");
var nodeTitle = document.createTextNode(profile[0].name);
var imgProfile = document.createElement("img");
imgProfile.src = profile[0].src;
imgProfile.alt = profile[0].alt;
var paraProfile = document.createElement("p");
var nodePara = document.createTextNode(profile[0].bio);
titleProfile.appendChild(nodeTitle);
paraProfile.appendChild(nodePara);
divMain.appendChild(imgProfile);
divMain.appendChild(paraProfile);
divMain.classList.add("bio");
popUp.appendChild(titleProfile);
popUp.appendChild(divMain);
};

function profileTwo() {
var divMain = document.createElement("div");
var titleProfile = document.createElement("h4");
var nodeTitle = document.createTextNode(profile[1].name);
var imgProfile = document.createElement("img");
imgProfile.src = profile[1].src;
imgProfile.alt = profile[1].alt;
var paraProfile = document.createElement("p");
var nodePara = document.createTextNode(profile[1].bio);
titleProfile.appendChild(nodeTitle);
paraProfile.appendChild(nodePara);
divMain.appendChild(imgProfile);
divMain.appendChild(paraProfile);
divMain.classList.add("bio");
popUp.appendChild(titleProfile);
popUp.appendChild(divMain);
}

if(triggerOne){
  triggerOne.addEventListener('click', function(){
    popUp.style.display = 'block';
    profileOne();
});
}

if(triggerTwo){
  triggerTwo.addEventListener('click', function(){
    popUp.style.display = 'block';
    profileTwo();
});
}


// Pop-Up window close

const invisible = e =>{
  popUp.style.display = 'none';
} 

if(close){
  close.addEventListener('click', invisible);
}
```

Comment: i’m on mobile at the moment, but answered a similar question the other day, it uses jQuery, but hopefully you will be able to understand the logic which could be recreated in plain js.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57458165 .  basically, on click, get the id of the element, and pass that through to your function and perform conditional handling based on the id.

Comment: Hi @user1063287! Thanks for the quick answer. I just had a look but unfortunately I have no idea how to make the jQuery code from that post into plan JS :/

Comment: ok, I’m sure someone will post solution before i get a chance, but if not, i’ll have a look when I get back on pc.

Comment: admission: i've never used plain js before (ducks), but [this jsFiddle seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/wy5a2r9x).  again, i'm not sure if i went against any plain js conventions, but it all looks pretty straightforward. i also added a bit of code that removes the content of the popup that was generated from the previous click, which your code wasn't doing.

Comment: @user1063287 Amazing! Thank you so much that worked like a charm!!